# How to handle null for IN clause in JPA query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Here `municipalities` parameter can be null. but IN clause doesnt work for null. If there was only one paramater i.e municipalities, I could have handle this in java level. but there is another condition in OR, which has to be executed.

```
List<Municipality> municipalities = myDao.findAll();  // returns empty list
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE m IN (:municipalities) OR m.city = :city")
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities)
 .setParameter("city", city)
    .getResultList();
```

So how to do this? Can we handle null in JPA IN clause. like if it is null then dont execute that condition

Comment: "SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE (:municipalities is not null and m IN (:municipalities)) OR m.city = :city"

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the query

```
String sql="";
if(municipalities!=null){
sql="SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE m IN (:municipalities) OR m.city = :city"
}
else
{
sql="SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE  m.city = :city"
}
List<Municipality> municipalities = myDao.findAll();  // returns empty list
em.createQuery(sql)
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities)
 .setParameter("city", city)
    .getResultList();
```